# hashtable that change value by itself

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

I am writing a java program using HashTable and I have a hard time using it. I have a HashTable object that between initialisation and reading, the values objects change

Since a piece of code is more understandable than a big paragraph, here it is :

```
   class localDictionnary {
       private Map<Entries, Symbol> dictionnary;
       public LocalDictionnary() {      
           this.dictionnary = new Hashtable<Entre, Symbole>();
       }
       public void add(Entries e, Symbol s) {
           dictionnary.put(e, s);
       }
       public void check() {
          int displacement = 0;
          for(Entry<Entries, Symbol> e : this.dictionnary.entrySet()){
              e.getValue().setDisplacement(displacement);
              displacement += e.getValue().getSize();
              System.out.print(e.getValue().getDisplacement() + " ");
          }
          System.out.println("");
          for(Entry<Entries, Symbol> e : this.dictionnary.entrySet())
              System.out.print(e.getValue().getDisplacement() + " ");
      }
   }
```

The outs of the program :

```
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
8 8 32 16 36 28 28 32 36 0
```

The displacements value are not the same between the first and the second call to println where it obviously should, even if the order has changed

The issue is not due to how HashTable sorts items, and the program is fully sequential so there is no other thread that blow every thing down...

I am not that new writing java program, but I have to say, this is the first time I use Hashtables...

Thanks a lot for your help =P

PS: I am not native english, so forgive me for my mistakes

Edit:

here is the piece of code that add a `<key, value>` to the HashMap, this is Java-cup code:

```
DECL_CHAMP  ::=     STATUS:s TYPE:t ID:id 
                {:
                    SymbolTable.add(new Entries(id), new Symbol(s, t));
                :}
        ;   
STATUS      ::=     PUBLIC
                {:
                    RESULT = Symbole.Statue.PUBLIC;
                :}
        |       PRIVATE
                {:
                    RESULT = Symbole.Statue.PRIVATE;
                :}
        ;
TYPE        ::=     INTEGER
                {:
                    RESULT = Symbole.Type.INTEGER;
                :}
        ;
```

Edit:
the identity of the the both print statements:

first print:
    `1271698539 1680090029` 
    `10643000 635758299` 
    `1458587468 635758299` 
    `953744171 1680090029` 
    `760340789 1519941073` 
    `1331632846 1826157335` 
    `390046421 1390107103` 
    `1055484408 1390107103` 
    `1311521036 1680090029` 
    `961899244 1826157335`

second print:
    `1271698539 1680090029` 
    `10643000 635758299` 
    `1458587468 635758299` 
    `953744171 1680090029` 
    `760340789 1519941073` 
    `1331632846 1826157335` 
    `390046421 1390107103` 
    `1055484408 1390107103` 
    `1311521036 1680090029` 
    `961899244 1826157335`

Comment: First things first, don't use a `Hashtable`, use a `HashMap`. It's not `synchronized` and is faster. `Hashtable` is deprecated.

Comment: Next question, do you perhaps have the same `Symbol` mapped to more than one `Entries`?

Comment: I first used HashMap, but there was the same issue, it was just a test to use HashTable

Comment: yes i have, actually, there are several Symbol that can be equal

Comment: See my answer. It should explain your problems.

Comment: `yes i have, actually, there are several Symbol that can be equal` Equal by _value_, or _equal_ by reference?

Comment: there are equals by value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> yes i have, actually, there are several Symbol that can be equal

A quick demonstration of the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
    System.out.printf("a:%s%n",a);
    final AtomicInteger b = a;
    System.out.printf("a:%s.b:%s%n", a, b);
    a.set(10);
    System.out.printf("a:%s.b:%s%n", a, b);
    b.set(5);
    System.out.printf("a:%s.b:%s%n", a, b);
}
```

Output:

```
a:0
a:0.b:0
a:10.b:10
a:5.b:5
```

So what is happening here? `AtomicInteger` is mutable. And Java passes references by value, so when we assign `b = a` what we do is copy the *reference* to the `AtomicInteger` that `a` references to a new reference `b`.

So when we change `a` we *also* change `b`.

How does this affect you? Well all we need to do is change the example slightly to exhibit the same behaviour:

```
final Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
map.put("aa", i);
map.put("bbbbb", i);
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    v.set(k.length());
    System.out.printf(" %s ", v);
});
System.out.println();
map.values().forEach(v -> System.out.printf(" %s ", v));
System.out.println();
```

Output:

```
 2  5 
 5  5
```

So when we change the value mapped to `bbbbb`, because the same object is also mapped to `aa` we change that value too.

**TL;DR: you need to understand how references work.**

P.S. A `Hashtable` or `HashMap` has **no order**. You need to use a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` if you want to loop over the `Map` and rely on the order of iteration - otherwise the order is not defined, but it can also change arbitrarily.

Comment: the thing is, the `Symbol` objects are equals, but there are different objects.

Comment: @nicoptere doesn't look like it from your example... I can see duplicate numbers which imply that, for example `[2] == [7]`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but each time I add a new <key, value> to the map, I create a new `Entries` and a new `Symbol`

Comment: @nicoptere you'll have to show us that code, because that is where your issue is it would seem.

Comment: @nicoptere There's something very odd about your question. Although BorisTheSpider is right that the iteration order is not guaranteed, it seems strange that the iteration order is different in the two `for` loops even though you don't add or remove any entries. I'm not very familiar with `Hashtable` so maybe that is possible, but I can't reproduce it. Can we see a complete, reproducible example?

Comment: @pbabcdefp that's not the issue I think - the _numbers_ are different and not the iteration order. `Hashtable` will preserve the iteration order between resizes.

Comment: But the order has changed. The last entry has value `36` in the first line of output. According to the OP's code, the value `36` should still be the value of that entry when it is printed in the second `for` loop. But for some reason the last number in the second line of output is `0`, not `36`. Unless I'm missing something, that doesn't make any sense at all. I think there is some information we're not being given.

Comment: @pbabcdefp undoubtedly there is something we're not being told.

Comment: here the order doesn't matter, what matters is that for the same hashmap, without changing it, the values change

Comment: @nicoptere Can you change the `print` statements in both loops to `System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(e.getKey()) + " " + System.identityHashCode(e.getValue()));` and tell us what it says?

Comment: I added the results in an edit of the my initial post (I don't know if it is the right place to add such thing...)

Comment: @nicoptere as you can clearly see, some objects have the same identity hash code. This means it's almost certain that multiple key's have mappings to the **same** object.

Comment: @nicoptere It is the right thing to do, and it shows that this answer is correct. The fact that `1680090029` is repeated (as are other values) shows that some values are the same instance, not just `equal()`. I still don't understand why the order has changed, but I think I'm going to give up trying to understand that.

Comment: @pbabcdefp look at the hashcodes - the order seems to be unchanged.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I saw that. I still can't understand how `36` can possibly be at the end of the first list but not the second. I must be missing something.

Comment: I just didn't have the idea to use the `clone()` methode... now, even the order is logical =D